# In the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, show that $2\in J$ where $J$ is the ideal $\langle i + 1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, show that $2 \in J$ where $J$ is the ideal $\langle i + 1\rangle$.

My thought was that $(1+i) \in J$ and $(1-i) \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$. Then if $\langle i + 1\rangle$ is an ideal, then $$\forall j\in J:\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}[i] :jk\in J\land kj\in J.$$ So it must be that $2 = (1+i)(1-i) = (1-i)(1+i) \in J$.

My problem is that when I list the elements of $\langle i + 1\rangle$, I don't see $2$.

Any help is appreciated finishing this.

Comment: How did you list the elements of $\langle 1+i \rangle$? $2$ must have appeared somewhere, because your first part is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by ''list the elements of $\langle i+1 \rangle$? This is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, so I'm not sure what you wrote down. Regardless, your proof looks fine, if a bit on the verbose side...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by list. Certainly since  $(1+i)(1-i)=2$, it follows  that $2\in J$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $<i+1> = \{ (i+1)^1 = (i+1),(i+1)^2 = -1 +1 -2i = -2i, (i+1)^3 = 2 -2i...,   \}$

Comment: @Nid: Those are the powers of $i+1$, which are certainly elements of the ideal $\langle i+1\rangle$... but the ideal $\langle i+1\rangle$ is comprised by all ***multiples*** of $i+1$, not just the powers. For example, the ideal $\langle 3\rangle$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ consists of
$$\langle 3\rangle=\{\ldots, -2\cdot 3 = -6,\;-1\cdot 3=-3,\;0\cdot 3 =0,\;1\cdot 3 = 3,\;2\cdot 3=6,\;\ldots\}$$
not
$$\langle 3\rangle=\{3^1=3,\;3^2=9,\;3^3=27,\;\ldots\}\quad \textbf{(incorrect)}$$

Comment: @ZevChonoles Oh ok. I see. So then what are the elements of the ring $⟨i+1⟩$?

Comment: @Nid: All the multiples of $i+1$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. That is, all of the Gaussian integers that can be produced by
$$(a+bi)\cdot (i+1)$$
for some $a+bi$ comprise the ideal $\langle i+1\rangle$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ok I see. My issue was with notation then. When I learned abstract algebra, in group theory, $<>$ referred to powers but apparently, it as a ring is different. Thank You everyone so much.

Comment: @Nid What Zev has said above is correct. You have listed the powers, not the entire ideal. The ideal may be related to the set of powers in some manner but it certainly is not equal. Maybe you are confusing the cyclic group notation with the ideal notation.

Comment: The user @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг seems to have found the source of confusion, the notation $\langle x\rangle$ can be used for "cyclic subgroup of a group $G$ generated by $x\in G$" and for "the ideal of a ring generated by $x\in R$".

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you're doing to list the elements of $\langle 1+i\rangle$ is incorrect, since everything else you wrote is the completely correct argument as to why $2\in\langle 1+ i\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

To "list" the elements, you have to use the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and not only $\mathbb{Z}$, or only the powers. There is no integer-mutiple of $(i+1)$ which is equal to $2$, but there is indeed an element $x\in R$ with $r(i+1)=2$, namley $x=1-i$.